# Get text from span with a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below HTML and JQuery code and i am needing some help to do the following, i have some radio buttons with freight types, when the user choose one of them i need to get its price, it is in the span with the class `price`. I've tried to use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) but i am getting and empty result (JQuery v1.7.2). Can anybody help me to get this?

**HTML**

```
<div class="freight">
    <input type="radio" name="freight-type" id="FX" value="FX" />
    <label for="FX">
        <span class="blue">Fedex</span>- 
        <strong>US$ <span class="price">12.42</span> </strong>
        <span class="small-text"> (Delivery time: <strong>3 business days)</strong></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$("input[name=freight-type]").change(function() {

    alert( $(this).closest(".price").text() )

});
```

Comment: Because  `.closest()` goes up the DOM tree. `.price` is one level below the radio button.

Comment: @AndrewPeacock, Thanks, i didn't pay attention in this detail! With Mike's answer i got what i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

closest() goes UP through the DOM tree, so it would starting looking in div.fregith and then go up the DOM tree from there.

try this as your selector:

```
$(this).next('label').find('.price')
```

Comment: Note that this would be more precise that the method proposed by Mike (that method works fine). This would only start searching for the price class starting with the sibling label element. So if you could potentially have multiple price class elements within the freight div, you would probably want to use this to get the very next price element as opposed to ALL the price elements.

Comment: Your solution really seems to be more precise

Comment: Thanks, i am using your suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/4AEyp/

an example

```
$("input[name='freight-type']").change(function() {
   alert($(this).parent().find('.price').text());
});​
```

Comment: This could potentially bring back a collection of similarly classed elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("input[name=freight-type]").change(function() { 
    alert( $(this).parent().find(".price:first").text() )
});
```

Comment: It's bring me an empty result too, maybe is because you aren't using `.parent()`, am i right?